# Facebook throws a JSONException when fetching email value

Tags: android, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I'm writing a Facebook Android app and one of the problems I'm encountering is getting users' email addresses. For all Facebook accounts except one, the email address is throwing an exception. Here's my code:

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    String accessToken = 
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                    Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest
                            (loginResult.getAccessToken(), new 
                             GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, 
                                  GraphResponse response)
                                {
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
                                      sharedPref.edit();
                                    try
                                    {

                                        editor.putString("user_ID", 
                                          object.getString("id"));
                                        user_ID = object.getString("id");
                                        editor.putString("user_name." + 
                                          user_ID, object.isNull("name") ? 
                                          "" : object.getString("name"));
                                        editor.putString("email_addr." + 
                                          user_ID, object.isNull("email") ? 
                                          "" : object.getString("email"));
                                        editor.commit();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(LaunchPage.this, getString(R.string.login_error) + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, birthday, timezone, picture, locale, age_range");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }
```

I've spent several days on this problem and I think I'm doing what was suggested in several other solutions posted, but my code still fails. I tried making my email address public in the failing Facebook accounts, but that didn't help.

Comment: What made you think you shouldn't include the error log in your question?

Comment: did you `setReadPermissions` in your `loginButton`?

Comment: @Denny What made you think the error log was relevant for this problem? And I wonder what fool down-voted my question.

Comment: Because in your question it says that there's an exception, and without knowing where it crashes, it's just guessing

Comment: @Denny It'd obvious where it's crashing: it's on object.getString("email"). I used Android Studio's debugger to get all the information I needed and it wasn't much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

add `setReadPermissions` in your `LoginButton`

```
 loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
 loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
```

Also make sure your `Email` is public in your Fb Account. Otherwise `Graph api` will not return it.

Comment: Making the email address public had no effect, as I mentioned in my original post. In any case, there wouldn't be many app users if they had to publish their email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly occurred to me that the one account whose email address is being returned is my own and that maybe it was connected with the fact that I'm the developer. So I checked my Facebook Developer Console and discovered a section, Roles, that lets you identify testers. So I added a couple of my test FB IDs and lo and behold, I was able to get their email addresses. Life is good again.